# ASP.NET MVC2 Can't get full id of element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, model, validation

I have this strongly typed view form for my model. Problem is that I can't seem to get the IDs right. My view model has form models within it so I have to call some elements like:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Business.Business2)%>
```

Problem is with this code:

```
viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(partialFieldName)
```

If my partialFieldName is "Business2" it should return "Business_Business2" but it only returns "Business2". However, if I use

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Business) %>
```

it returns "Business_Business2". I can't use Html.EditorFor since I have css classes to place on my form elements. I can't do much of my client side validations without the right Id so this has really been bugging me. Any ideas?

Here are my codes:

**Models**

```
public class BusinessModel
    {
        public string Business1 { get; set; }
        public string Business2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountModel
    {
        public string Account1 { get; set; }

        [MustMatch("Account1")]
        public string Account2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SampleWrappedModel
    {
        public BusinessModel Business { get; set; }
        public AccountModel Account { get; set; }
    }
```

**Validations**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class MustMatchAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "Must match {0}";

        public MustMatchAttribute(string propertyToMatch)
            : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
        {
            PropertyToMatch = propertyToMatch;
        }

        public string PropertyToMatch { get; private set; }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString, PropertyToMatch);
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            throw new Exception("MustMatchAttribute requires the DataAnnotationsMustMatchValidator adapter to be registered"); 
        }
    }

    //Adapter class
    public class DataAnnotationsMustMatchValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<MustMatchAttribute>
    {
        public DataAnnotationsMustMatchValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, MustMatchAttribute attribute)
            : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
        }

        public override System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
        {
            var propertyToMatch = Metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(Attribute.PropertyToMatch);
            if (propertyToMatch != null)
            {
                var valueToMatch = propertyToMatch.GetValue(container, null);
                var value = Metadata.Model;

                bool valid = Equals(value, valueToMatch);
                if (!valid)
                {
                    yield return new ModelValidationResult { Message = ErrorMessage };
                }
            }
        }

        public override System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            string propertyIdToMatch = GetFullHtmlFieldId(Attribute.PropertyToMatch);
            yield return new ModelClientMustMatchValidationRule(ErrorMessage, propertyIdToMatch);
        }

        private string GetFullHtmlFieldId(string partialFieldName)
        {
            ViewContext viewContext = (ViewContext)ControllerContext;
            return viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(partialFieldName);
        }
    }

    public class ModelClientMustMatchValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        public ModelClientMustMatchValidationRule(string errorMessage, string propertyIdToMatch)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;

            ValidationType = "mustMatch";

            ValidationParameters.Add("propertyIdToMatch", propertyIdToMatch);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the TemplateInfo does with GetFullHtmlFieldName and GetFullHtmlFieldId methods, is simply prepending [HtmlFieldPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.htmlfieldprefix.aspx) to passed partialFieldName. If I understood correctly, you need kind of helper able to return html field name from labmda expression

```
 public static string GetHtmlFieldName<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
 {
     return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
 }
```

And then you could use

```
Html.GetHtmlFieldName(m => m.Business.Business2)
```

This will return `Business.Business2`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think this would work but I need to pass the Full field name/id from the server to the client so simply using Html.GetHtmlFieldName in my view won't work for me. I tried getting the HtmlFieldPrefix via TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix but it just returns an empty string. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Do you need to pass that for javascript or for css #id selector?

Comment: Yes. It's for client-side model validation so I need to pass it from the DataAnnotations to ModelClientValidationFule to the javascript on the client side.

Comment: Is there a way to use the GetHtmlFieldName in the DataAnnotationsModelValidator to replace TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName? Thank you so much for replying.

Comment: I'll take a look when i have time and inform you

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use Html.EditorFor since I have css classes to place on my form elements.

You could write a custom editor template then. So in your view:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Business) %>
```

and then inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/BusinessModel.ascx`:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<BusinessModel>" %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Business1) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Business2) %>
...
```

or if you don't like the conventional places and names for templates you could customize that as well:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Business, "MyBusinessTemplate") %>
```

or if it is only a matter of applying additional attributes to your input elements you could do it in an even more elegant way: by [writing a custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx).

I would recommend you to always use `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`.